# Any way to install myodbc 2.50.39-nt on a 64bit windows 7 computer?

Tags: mysql, vb6, odbc

Is there anyway to install myodbc 2.50.39-nt on a 64bit windows 7 computer? (it says 'the version of this file is not compatable with the version of windows that you are running')
I have a few old VB6 programs that use it (almost all of it has been moved to a private intranet)

If it isn't possible, it looks like the newer version of myodbc would work. Anyone have any idea what all the differences are between the two versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to get myodbc 2.50 installed. But I did simply change the connection string to use myodbc 3.51 and it works.